# How to get "clean" match results in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, match

I am a total noob, coding for the first time and trying to learn by doing. 
I'm using this:

```
import re
f = open('aaa.txt', 'r')
string=f.read()
c = re.findall(r"Guest last name: (.*)", string)
print "Dear Mr.", c
```

that returns

```
Dear Mr. ['XXXX']
```

I was wondering, is there any way to get the result like

```
Dear Mr. XXXX
```

instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that true that you only have a name up to the end of the line? I'd use something like `\S+` rather than `.*` - `r"Guest last name: (\S+)"`. Or `\S*` if it can be empty. Anyway, check the result before using.

Comment: anytime something returns a ['something'] that means it's in an array and you need to access it with [n] where n is the position of the element in the array.

Comment: Fortunately the exported document I am reading in Python has 1 string per line, so I have a very easy time with regex. However I will still try to make it more accurate, both for the actual code and to learn regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the first item in the list

```
print "Dear Mr.", c[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes use `re.search` if you only expect one match:

```
re.search(r"Guest last name: (.*)", string).group(1)`
```

findall is if you expect multiple matches. You probably want to also add `?` to your regex `(.*?)` for a non-greedy capture but you also probably want to be a little more specific and capture up to the next possible character after the name/phrase you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into more complex regexes, for now I am just building the skeleton! I tried using re.search, but it returns "<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000361DBE8>". I guess that means it found a match and where the match is, but I need the actual match in my output :)